# Asp.Net MVC: using HTML tags in @Html:Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to use inline HTML inside a @Html.Grid (I'm trying to create a hyperlink tag in one of the columns).  Here is an example:

```
@model Example.Models.ExampleItems

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Example Items";
}

<div id="ExampleContentInnerContainer">
<h2>Example Items</h2>

<div id="ExampleListGrid">
    <span class="ExampleGrid">
    <p>
        @Html.Grid(Model.ExampleList).Columns(c =>
        {
            c.For(a => a.Example.Mandatory == true ? "Yes" : "No").Named("Mandatory");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateRequested)).Named("Date Requested");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateDeadline)).Named("Deadline Date");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateReceived)).Named("Date Received");         
            c.For(a => a.Comment).Named("Comment");
            c.For(a => a.Name).Named("Checklist type");
            c.For(a => @:<a href="www.google.com" />);
        }
        )
    </p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Any help would be welcomed.

**UPDATE** - based on archil's post, my new code has become:

```
@model Example.Models.ExampleItems

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Example Items";

    Func<dynamic, object> updateLink = @<a href="#?w=500" rel="Checklist_Popup" class="poplight">@item</a>;
}

<div id="ExampleContentInnerContainer">
<h2>Example Items</h2>

<div id="ExampleListGrid">
    <span class="ExampleGrid">
    <p>
        @Html.Grid(Model.ExampleList).Columns(c =>
        {
            c.For(a => a.Example.Mandatory == true ? "Yes" : "No").Named("Mandatory");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateRequested)).Named("Date Requested");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateDeadline)).Named("Deadline Date");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateReceived)).Named("Date Received");         
            c.For(a => a.Comment).Named("Comment");
            c.For(a => a.Name).Named("Checklist type");
            c.For(a => updateLink("Update"));        
        }
        )
    </p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [templated razor delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx). There you could do your link generation

Answer (score 0):

You could try by wrapping "<a>...</a>" in "@<text>...</text>" tag.
In your case it would look like so:

```
@model Example.Models.ExampleItems

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Example Items";
}

<div id="ExampleContentInnerContainer">
<h2>Example Items</h2>

<div id="ExampleListGrid">
    <span class="ExampleGrid">
    <p>
        @Html.Grid(Model.ExampleList).Columns(c =>
        {
            c.For(a => a.Example.Mandatory == true ? "Yes" : "No").Named("Mandatory");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateRequested)).Named("Date Requested");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateDeadline)).Named("Deadline Date");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateReceived)).Named("Date Received");         
            c.For(a => a.Comment).Named("Comment");
            c.For(a => a.Name).Named("Checklist type");
            c.For(a => @<text><a href="www.google.com" /></text>);
        }
        )
    </p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. When i try it this way, unfortunately i get: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type.